# Specifying a column to compare in HAVING subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, ssms, adventureworks

I am trying to compare sales from different quarters by stores in adventureworks 2014.
My code is as following

```
SELECT store.BusinessEntityID as "StoreID",  "Name"
from sales.SalesOrderHeader
inner join sales.customer 
    on sales.SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID = sales.customer.CustomerID
inner join sales.store 
    on sales.customer.StoreID= sales.store.BusinessEntityID
where (OrderDate between '2014-01-01' and '2014-03-31')
    and (OnlineOrderFlag = 0)
group by store.BusinessEntityID, "Name"
having format(round(sum(subtotal),2),'###,###,###.##') > format(round(sum(subtotal),2),'###,###,###.##') IN
(
   SELECT store.BusinessEntityID as "StoreID",
   format(round(sum(subtotal),2),'###,###,###.##') "Ventes2013_Q4"
   from sales.SalesOrderHeader
   inner join sales.customer on sales.SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID =     sales.customer.CustomerID
   inner join sales.store on sales.customer.StoreID= sales.store.BusinessEntityID
   where (orderdate between '2013-10-01' and '2013-12-31') and OnlineOrderFlag = 0
   group by store.BusinessEntityID
)
```

Both my main query and my subquery work individually, but I am not able to specify the column i want to compare it with in the second part of the having. When trying IN it gives me an incorrect syntax, and it does not work when using the column name either. It also did not work when adding a sales column in the main query
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Which SQL platform are you using?

Comment: MS sql server management studio

Comment: What do you wnat to compare it to?

Comment: I want to show the stores that have more sales in 2014Q1 than in 2013Q4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 With Ventes2014_Q1 as(
SELECT store.BusinessEntityID as "StoreID",  "Name",format(round(sum(subtotal),2),'###,###,###.##') "Ventes2014_Q1"
from sales.SalesOrderHeader
inner join sales.customer 
    on sales.SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID = sales.customer.CustomerID
inner join sales.store 
    on sales.customer.StoreID= sales.store.BusinessEntityID
where (OrderDate between '2014-01-01' and '2014-03-31')
    and (OnlineOrderFlag = 0)
group by store.BusinessEntityID, "Name"
),Ventes2013_Q4
(
   SELECT store.BusinessEntityID as "StoreID",
   format(round(sum(subtotal),2),'###,###,###.##') "Ventes2013_Q4"
   from sales.SalesOrderHeader
   inner join sales.customer on sales.SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID =     sales.customer.CustomerID
   inner join sales.store on sales.customer.StoreID= sales.store.BusinessEntityID
   where (orderdate between '2013-10-01' and '2013-12-31') and OnlineOrderFlag = 0
   group by store.BusinessEntityID
) 
select "StoreID",  "Name" from Ventes2014_Q1 
where "StoreID" exists 
        (select "StoreID" from Ventes2013_Q4 where Ventes2013_Q4."StoreID"=Ventes2014_Q1."StoreID" and Ventes2014_Q1."Ventes2014_Q1">Ventes2013_Q4."Ventes2013_Q4")
```

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to compare values that have been formatted as strings.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way to do it (translating from your code)

```
SELECT StoreID, Name
FROM (
  SELECT store.BusinessEntityID as "StoreID",  "Name", sum(stubtotal) as sum
  from sales.SalesOrderHeader
  inner join sales.customer on sales.SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID =   sales.customer.CustomerID
  inner join sales.store on sales.customer.StoreID= sales.store.BusinessEntityID
  where (OrderDate between '2014-01-01' and '2014-03-31') and (OnlineOrderFlag = 0)
  group by store.BusinessEntityID, "Name"
) first
JOIN (
   SELECT BusinessEntityID, sum(subtotal) as sum
   from sales.SalesOrderHeader
   inner join sales.customer on sales.SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID =     sales.customer.CustomerID
   inner join sales.store on sales.customer.StoreID= sales.store.BusinessEntityID
   where (orderdate between '2013-10-01' and '2013-12-31') and OnlineOrderFlag = 0
   group by store.BusinessEntityID
) as sub on sub.BusinessEntityID = furst.BusinessEntityID 
        AND sub.sum < first.sum
```

However there is a better way in sql server... one sec.

This will give to you totals by quarter and store:

```
  SELECT 
    store.BusinessEntityID as StoreID,
    Name,
    year(OrderDate) as y,
    quarter(orderdate) as q,
    sum(stubtotal) as sum
  from sales.SalesOrderHeader
  inner join sales.customer on sales.SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID =   sales.customer.CustomerID
  inner join sales.store on sales.customer.StoreID= sales.store.BusinessEntityID
  group by store.BusinessEntityID, Name, year(OrderDate), quarter(orderdate)
```

Now create a view

```
 CREATE VIEW quarterview as
    SELECT 
      store.BusinessEntityID as StoreID,
      Name,
      year(OrderDate) as y,
      quarter(orderdate) as q,
      sum(stubtotal) as sum
    from sales.SalesOrderHeader
    inner join sales.customer on sales.SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID =   sales.customer.CustomerID
    inner join sales.store on sales.customer.StoreID= sales.store.BusinessEntityID
    group by store.BusinessEntityID, Name, year(OrderDate), quarter(orderdate)
```

"I want to show the stores that have more sales in 2014Q1 than in 2013Q4"

```
  SELECT *
  FROM quarterview first
  WHERE q = 1 and year = 2014
```

then

```
  SELECT *
  FROM quarterview first
  JOIN quarterview second ON second.q = 4 and second.year=2013 and first.sum > second.sum 
  WHERE first.q = 1 and first.year = 2014
```

With your fab new quarter view all the client request are easy to do with just a couple of lines of code.